Nat PREROUTING chain unable to route packets to loopback interface
I have a service running on 127.0.0.1:3000, I want to forward any packets arriving on eth28 to that service.
I created a dummy interface on my machine.
$ ip link add eth28 type dummy
$ ip addr add 10.10.0.5/24 dev eth28
$ ip link set dev eth28 up

I want to route the packets coming into the interface to a destination IP & port.
I tried adding the following PREROUTING rules -
$ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth28 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:3000
$ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth28 -d 10.10.0.5 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:3000

I have a server running at 127.0.0.1:3000.
$ python3 -m http.server 3000 --bind 127.0.0.1

I am trying to redirect packets via curl, however
$ curl http://10.10.0.5:3000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.10.0.5 port 3000: Connection refused

Only rule that worked was -
$ iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 10.10.0.5 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:3000

However, this is IP address based filtering and not interface based filtering.
OUTPUT chain does not have an input interface (-i option), Pre-routing chain doesn't filter input interfaces.
What is a way to achieve this use-case?

I am trying to redirect packets via curl, however — what, again, you are trying to do? curl does not do "packet redirection". It's a high level network client. // What is your intention (a.k.a. define the "use-case")? Why won't you bind directly to the IP address you want to receive packets on? // Yes, OUTPUT chain can't specify input interface, because it absolutely doesn't have any. It's for packets originated on the system, not the ones that came in it through some interface. Think as if there was a dedicated "system interface" and the INPUT/OUTPUT chains are for that.

-i means traffics that ingress into the host via the specified interface, NOT traffics with destination IP that is the IP configured on the interface. And indeed, why would you even think of dummy anyway? What's your real goal?

Also for communication redirected to a loopback address to work, you'll need to set the route_localnet sysctl to 1, I think.

@NikitaKipriyanov I have a service running on 127.0.0.1:3000, I want to forward any packets arriving on eth28 to that service. curl is how I'm sending packets to eth28's IP and want them to get redirected to 127.0.0.1:3000. I'm not sure, how'd I match packets arriving at the created interface and route them to 127.0.0.1:3000.

@TomYan route_localnet would penalize other traffic though. Using an interface to reserve the IP address and have a clean separation between traffic. Hence, using a dummy interface.

No idea what you mean by "penalize" or "clean separation". When you DNAT traffics (from another host) to a loopback address (e.g. 127.0.0.1), you'll need route_localnet to be 1, otherwise the traffics would be dropped. And you are not making any sense about the dummy -- no traffics would "arrive on" that interface, regardless of what destination IP a packet has.

Suppose you have a real interface (let's call it not_dummy), and some other host in the network not_dummy attached to have a route for the address configured on dummy (and ARP response is sent to that host for resolution on this address), the traffics from the other host still "arrive on" not_dummy, regardless of whether the destination address is the one configured on not_dummy or the one configured on dummy. Your OS is not a "dummy" -- it can tell which interface traffics "arrive on".

*I have a service running on 127.0.0.1:3000, I want to forward any packets arriving on eth28 to that service. * — well, first of all, this is how your question should have been begun. Look at my edit, that's much more clear what you want. Next, what is the purpose of that? That "dummy" interface is almost no different from lo  — why won't you bind your service directly to "dummy"? Else, what is the purpose of the dummy interface, why are you introducing it? (By the way, if that's just a means to assign an additional address to the system, you can just do ip addr add 10.10.0.5/24 dev lo.)

The lo driver on certain kernel versions expressly rejects the ability to send packets outside of local, even if the IP is LAN. While this is the Cisco way, I would avoid doing that on Linux. Dummy and bridge interfaces are a better option.

@RobertGlonek why would the "driver" of an interface that is not the one traffics go out of be relevant? (and there's no real "come in from" interface when we are talking replies from the host itself, and the only "pseudo" interface (name) would / can be used to refer to such traffics is lo, regardless of which interface the source IP is configured on)

@TomYan I’m talking about packets coming in and out of the interfaces, not lo. That driver loads certain routing rules to the NIC firmware itself to offload some routing decisions. It seems to directly tie in to what rules I add in iptables and use that. So the NIC can actually route packets (it’s got 4 ports) between ports without ever involving the CPU. If the routing requires I come out via a different card, CPU is involved, but for routing from if1 to if2 on same card, the firmware can do it itself without the PC, using firmware rules the driver loads from my iptables. It feels wrong…

You have the right idea except you are connecting from the local machine to itself. According to the flowcharts, if source is local host, the nat PREROUTING is not invoked. See: https://stuffphilwrites.com/2014/09/iptables-processing-flowchart/
Also, for connecting from outside, if you use DNAT for prerouting, remember to also masquerade your IP for return packets using SNAT or MASQ on POSTROUTING.

Right, for local processes the PREROUTING rule would not be invoked. I'm trying to see if we can also do it for non-local packets.

For non-local, your prerouting rules are fine. What you are missing is a postrouting rule. If you DNAT packets on the way out, you need to SNAT them on the way back. See this for examples: https://gist.github.com/tomasinouk/eec152019311b09905cd

@RobertGlonek "reverse SNAT" is done automatically / "statefully". You only need an SNAT/MASQUERADE rule when you are DNAT'ing to another host and if this host is not the other host's default gateway (to allow the "reverse SNAT" to occur).

@TomYan so I worked it out why I need the rule and you don’t. Funny fact, my cheap laptop and Pc and NAS NICs don’t need the SNAT rule. My expensive test servers with their fancy HP NICs and drivers support rule offloading to the NIC. Iptables rules are translated by the driver and offloaded to the NIC, which does a really bad job and fails without a corresponding SNAT rule also specifically implemented. Worked this out accidentally as I noticed that during tcpdump I don’t need a SNAT rule lol. When running, tcpdump puts the NIC in promisc mode which stops the offloading. That was a weird one.

@Sprite things to try: add the POSTROUTING MASQ rule, put the NIC in promisc mode if the NIC is physical, ensure your FORWARD chain is ACCEPT, and ensure the sysctl ip_forward is set to 1. Pretty sure it’s one (or more) of these that causes your problem. You must have the correct FORWARD ACCEPT and ip_forward sysctl switch set to 1 for PREROUTING port forwarding to work.

@RobertGlonek If you say so. I have no idea whether "iptables rule offloading" is a real thing, or how it could be, or what exactly does it mean (when each chain can have rules that may or may not concern a specific interface, explicitly/only or implicitly/generally).

@RobertGlonek btw, when you DNAT to the host itself, it would literally "change" the "nature" of the traffics from "forward" to "input" if the original destination address is a "remote" address. So please, don't even mention anything related to IP forwarding. Calling DNAT "port forwarding" won't automagically associate it to IP forwarding...

@TomYan no, the question asker changed the question in their first comment to my post, asking for non-local packets. Re offloading, don’t ask me, I only work here. I have to keep the interface in promisc mode for the normal iptables behaviour and changing iptables rules causes the driver to reload the firmware with IPs I mentioned in iptables. I only know this from testing. Feels like a bad idea, but it is what it is.

@RobertGlonek by "non-local" he meant the actual "case" he cares about is that when the traffics was sent from another host (instead of sending from this host to this host, i.e. the loopback "output" case). The destination host in concern has always been "this host". Please read the question again. (He never had any problem with the loopback "output" case. See Only rule that worked was. That's why he said "non-local". Because you try to explain / address something that has been working / not really of his concern in the first half of your answer, right from the beginning.)

@RobertGlonek More precisely, I don't know if he really cares about any "non-local" case either. The truth is, he hasn't given any (understandable) information regarding what he really want to do and/or why was he trying what he was trying. We still have no idea at all why a dummy interface a non-loopback address was introduced. (Maybe he thought dummy + non-loopback address ~= veth pair + netns?) And somehow, you seem to have assumed that he was talking about / setting up a "router", when he obviously was not.

@TomYan that’s fair. There isn’t enough information about what he wants to achieve and what the topology really is. I’m going to fade out and continue my vacation I think. All the best.

If you could extract the relevant bit from the blog link, this will help prevent link rot in future! I would quote the relevant bit and leave the link as a source. :)
